# Ruby on Rails - passing a returned value of a method to has_attached_file. Do I get Ruby syntax wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm writing my first RoR app and currently I'm working on allowing users to upload images. I'm using [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) for this purpose. One of the steps involves adding `has_attached_file` to my model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  has_attached_file :picture, styles: {
    large: "120x150#>", 
    small: "60x75#>"
  }
  #...
end
```

If I do it like this, everything works smoothly (or so it seems). But I will also need to access the same constant values as integers somewhere else, so I've added a hash:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  has_attached_file :picture, styles: {
    large: "120x150#>", 
    small: "60x75#>"
  }
  def picture_sizes
  {
    large: {width: 120, height: 150},
    small: {width: 60, height: 75}
  }
  end
  #...
end
```

This creates an ugly redundancy. So I thought about writing a method generating the first hash from the second one, like this

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  has_attached_file :picture, styles: picture_sizes_as_strings

  def picture_sizes
  {
    large: {width: 120, height: 150},
    small: {width: 60, height: 75}
  }
  end

  def picture_sizes_as_strings
    result = {}
    picture_sizes.each do |label, size|
      result[:label] = "#{size[:width]}x#{size[:height]}#>"
    end
    return result
  end
  #...
end
```

But this rises an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `picture_sizes_as_strings' for #<Class:0x007fdf504d3870>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use an instance method `picture_sizes_as_strings` in a declaration (`has_attached_image`) that's run on the class level. It's the difference between calling

```
MyModel.picture_sizes_as_strings
```

and

```
MyModel.first.picture_sizes_as_strings
```

In the first case we are referring to a class method (a method on the class MyModel itself) and in the second case we are referring to an instance method (a method on the individual my_model object.)

So first of all you have to change the methods to class methods by prefixing their names with `self.`, so:

```
def self.picture_sizes
  {
    large: {width: 120, height: 150},
    small: {width: 60, height: 75}
  }
end
```

Now that doesn't completely fix your problem yet, because `has_attached_image` is processed when the model is first parsed by ruby. That means it will try to run `has_attached_image` before you define `self.picture_sizes` so it will still say `undefined method`.

You can fix this by putting `self.picture_sizes` before the `has_attached_file` declaration but that's quite ugly. You could also put the data in a constant but that has its own problems.

Honestly there's no really pretty way to fix this. If it were me I'd probably reverse the whole process, define the styles as normal and then use a method to convert the strings to integers, something like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :picture, styles: {
    large: "120x150#>", 
    small: "60x75#>"
  }

  def numeric_sizes style
    # First find the requested style from Paperclip::Attachment
    style = self.picture.styles.detect { |s| s.first == style.to_sym }

    # You can consolidate the following into one line, I will split them for ease of reading
    # First strip all superfluous characters, we just need the numerics and the 'x' to split them
    sizes = style.geometry.gsub(/[^0-9x]/,'')
    # Next split the two numbers across the 'x'
    sizes = sizes.split('x')
    # Finally convert them to actual integer numbers
    sizes = sizes.map(&:to_i)
  end
end
```

Then you can call `MyModel.first.numeric_sizes(:medium)` to find out the sizes for a specific style, returned as an array. Of course you could change them into a hash too or whatever format you need.

Answer (score 1):

the `has_attached_file` is evaluated at Runtime.  You've defined an instance method, but you aren't calling the method from an instance context.

Try:

```
def self.picture_sizes_as_strings
  # code here
end
```

Make sure you define the other method with `self.` also

and then:

```
has_attached_file :picture, :styles => picture_sizes_as_strings
```

should work.

Comment: You mean I should add `self.` to both `picture_sizes_as_strings` and `picture_sizes`? I've tried, still the same error. I've also tried adding `MyModel::` to the call of `picture_sizes_as_strings`, then the error message changes to `undefined method 'picture_sizes_as_strings' for #<Class:0x00000004504e30>`