# add methods directly called on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rubygems, customization

I would like to implement my own method called on class load.

The first example I have is from `PaperClip` where the line `has_attached_file` is written directly on the class and refers to another implantation somewhere around (lib/Paperclip).

I would like to implement a method to be called for some other method on a class. I want it to looks link a `before_filter` but on a model.

This idea is to not have to call a specific method manually on each method you want to. Just one line at the beginning of the model should be enough to do it.

I tried using `Concern` but as far as I know, I can only define class/instance methods, include some dependencies and so on.

I would like to call the method `watch_here` for 2 methods `go_for_it` and `do_it_again`. I don't want to call it like that:

```
def go_for_it
  watch_here :go_for_it
  puts "Do it!"
end

def do_it_again
  watch_here :do_it_again
  puts "Do it again!"
end

private
def watch_here(name)
  puts "I'm watching on #{name}"
end
```

I would rather have something like:

```
watch_here :go_for_it, :do_it_again
```

Thank you for you help!

Comment: Can you give context? This is a job for [`concerns`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) but I need to know what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I've added some details. Is it enough?

Comment: So what you want to do is add a hook which basically injects code in a `before_action` style, to methods you define?

Comment: I've wanted to do something similar. I don't have any code, I'll have a read for you

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do and currently I'm not able to do it. Thank for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I tested this myself && further to `@max`'s answer (which I kind of thought anyway, but he definitely pointed it out properly)...

---

There are a number of resources you can use:

- Paperclip's [`has_attached_file`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/ClassMethods#has_attached_file-instance_method)
- FriendlyID's [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/base.rb#L196)
- [Ruby Metaprogramming: Declaratively Adding Methods to a Class](http://www.vitarara.org/cms/ruby_metaprogamming_declaratively_adding_methods_to_a_class)
- [Intend to extend](http://www.medihack.org/2011/03/15/intend-to-extend/)

After some brief researching, I found this question:
[Ruby on Rails - passing a returned value of a method to has_attached_file. Do I get Ruby syntax wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132991/ruby-on-rails-passing-a-returned-value-of-a-method-to-has-attached-file-do-i)

> The problem is that you're trying to use an instance method `picture_sizes_as_strings` in a **declaration** (`has_attached_image`)

What you're looking for is something to do with declaring a class. I have as much experience as you with this, so I'm writing this for my own benefit:

> For those coming from static object oriented languages, such as C++ and Java, the concept of **open classes** is quite foreign. What does it mean that Ruby has open classes? It means that **at run time the *definition* of a class can be changed**. All classes in Ruby are open to be changed by the user at all times.

```
class Talker
  def self.say(*args)
    puts "Inside self.say"
    puts "self = #{self}"
    args.each do |arg|
      method_name = ("say_" + arg.to_s).to_sym
      send :define_method, method_name do
        puts arg
      end
    end
  end
end

class MyTalker < Talker
  say :hello
end

m = MyTalker.new

m.say_hello
```

It seems that if you *delcare* the class, it will run the declarative (?) methods at init. These methods can be used to populate other parts of the object... in the case of `has_many :associations`, it would create an instance method of `@parent.associations`.

Since [`ActiveRecord::Concerns`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) are modules, you need to treat them as such (according to the [epic tutorial](http://www.vitarara.org/cms/ruby_metaprogamming_declaratively_adding_methods_to_a_class) I found):

```
#app/models/concerns.rb
require 'active_support/concern'

module Helper
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def help(*args) #-> each argument represents a method
      args.each do |arg|
        method_name = ("say_" + arg.to_s).to_sym
        send :define_method, method_name do
          puts arg
        end
      end
    end
  end

end

#app/models/x.rb
class X < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Helper
  help :help
end

@x = X.new
@x.say_help #-> puts "help"
```

---

[[still working out the rest]] -- how to add to instance methods; seems `super` doesn't work so well

Comment: I think what helped me most is realising that OO in Ruby is more like JavaScript or Smalltalk. Ruby classes have nothing in common with the static stone tablets you have in Java, C+ or even PHP. Classes are just objects that are factories and prototypes.

Comment: It's almost done thanks to you guys. I'm now looking to inject code on an **existing** method. I don't want to create a new one. My `help :foo, :bar` inject code on existing `foo` and `bar`method. Like that I'm sure that this code will be execute as first.

Comment: Hum.. What about this class used by a lib (and only a lib)? I can't include a concern on a class not inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base` isn't it?

Comment: To do it I had to use @max's answer and calling manually this method. It could be awesome if this method was on a lib. In that way it would be easy to use it almost everywhere on my app.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from using `define_method` inside of `instance_eval` or  `class_eval` - you just have to pay attention to what `self` is.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the joys of meta-programming! To dynamically add methods or behavior to a class you would use [`instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) and [`class_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-class_eval).

Note that this is a pretty advanced subject and that you should have a fair understanding of how classes, modules and message passing in Ruby works first!

- http://rubykoans.com/
- http://www.rubyinside.com/media/poignant-guide.pdf

---

```
module Magic
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end
  module ClassMethods
    def make_awesome
      # self here is the class - so we are adding class methods
      self.instance_eval do
        def magic_class_method
          puts "I'm a metamagical class method, deal with it."
        end
        # you could call another class method such as
        # before_save :magic_instance_method
      end
      self.class_eval do
        def magic_instance_method
          puts "I'm metamagical instance method, deal with it."
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class Test
  include Magic
  make_awesome
end

Test.magic_class_method 
# => "I'm a metamagical class method, deal with it."
Test.magic_instance_method 
# => "I'm metamagical instance method, deal with"
```

This is kind of counter-intuitive but there is a reason behind the madness:

In `instance_eval` the receiver is the Test class itself. Remember that a class name is simply a constant which points to an instance of the class `Class`.

`class_eval` is a method of the Module class, meaning that the receiver will be a module or a class. The block you pass to class_eval is evaluated in the context of that class just like when you declare a class with the `class` keyword.

Additional reading:

- http://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/metaprogramming-ruby-class-eval-and-instance-eval/
- https://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr2/metaprogramming-ruby

Comment: So am I right in thinking that what you're doing is creating a method which responds to both class and instance level invocation? How would that fit in with calling `has_attached_file` etc?

Comment: That's spot on! The missing word was `meta-programming`. I'll take a deeper look at documents you gave me. Do you have an idea to inject code on method passed on a splat parameter?

Comment: http://www.vitarara.org/cms/ruby_metaprogamming_declaratively_adding_methods_to_a_class

Comment: "Ruby class definitions are evaluated at run time" -- this is where the `instance_eval` & `class_eval` come from

Comment: Oh okay I get it (I think). The `has_many` or `has_attached_file` declaration is there to provide functionality for *other* features? For example, `has_many :associations` appends an `associations` method onto the parent object

Comment: @bobbystouket, you can use `define_method` if you want to define methods on the class / instance dynamically such as from a splat. https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/2-metaprogramming-ruby/chapters/25-dynamic-methods/lessons/72-define-method

Comment: @RichardPeck yes, most of the Rails DSL stuff like associations, validations, callbacks etc are built around a pattern similar to this. Thats where all the "magic" comes from :)